# The shared library contains the string. Why can't my program find it?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, rhel

When I run my program, I get this output:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb_glx"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbGlxIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328960
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb_glx")
Cannot load library /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so: (/home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so" : "Cannot load library /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so: (/home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl)"
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
```

And yet when I look inside the library, I seem to find the symbol it can't find.

```
tester@localhost~/work/230627_1500$ strings /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so | grep _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl
_ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl
```

Is the symbol "not there" in some other sense?  Is there a command I can run to see the symbols that are available in the library?

I am running on RedHat linux.  The program was built with QtCreator if that matters.

The program in fact fails to display the image I was expecting.  I seem to be giving it the wrong library.  But it appears to me . . . that the library is right.

Comment: You need to use `nm` (probably `nm -D`) not `strings`.

Comment: tester@localhost~/work/230627_1500$ nm /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so | grep _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl
nm: /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so: no symbols  

tester@localhost~/work/230627_1500$ nm -D /home/tester/vdcds/mmd_2.1/bin/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so | grep _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl
                 U _ZN10QXcbWindow18handleGenericEventEP19xcb_generic_event_tPl  

Thanks n.m.  Still don't see why cant find it.

Comment: The letter U, do you think it stands foр "U r welcome"? No ;)

Comment: "Undefined"   So the symbol exists in the file internally, perhaps used by other functions, but it's not exposed for external use.   I'm using a program written by another programmer a long time ago.   Maybe when he wrote it, the version of the library he was using had that symbol exposed.   Thank you, n. m.   Things are clearer.

Comment: No, "undefined" doesn't mean that. Undefined means undefined. It's not there. The name is there, because the library wants to call the function, so it knows its name. But the function itself is not there. It is supposed to be supplied by some other library (guess: libxcb?) or by the program itself.

Comment: Every time you say something, it gets clearer.  :)  The message is:  Cannot load library /home/.../libqxcb-glx-integration.so: (/home/.../libqxcb-glx-integration.so: undefined symbol: _ZN1...handleGenericEvent..._tPl)   I cannot imagine that the program is seeing through this library to see another library that is lacking a symbol.   Unless it's reporting an error that this library is reporting to it.